# 文言 もんごん ぶんげん why are the differences between these two readings and why is もんごん more common?

Tags: etymology, readings

As stated in the title the reading for 文言 can be もんごん or ぶんげん. I know that もんごん is almost always used in speech, but why do two readings exist and why is もんごん so much more common? Also, are their any specific circumstances when ぶんげん is preferred?

Comment: 「せろん」と「よろん」みたいなもの？私は「もんごん」しか知りませんでした。「文言一致」は「ぶんげんいっち」だなあ・・・（と思ったら"[言文]{げんぶん}"一致？）

Comment: もんごん is the 呉音 reading, and 文言 is the 漢音 reading.

Comment: @ちょこれーと: Zhen linのコメントで答えがわかった。文言一致という熟語は明治時代にできたから、漢音読みです。（明治時代にできた熟語はほとんど漢音読みです。）ただ、それ以前に「文言」という言葉があったから、２つの読み方が存在してるわけです。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

もんごん is the 呉音 reading, and ぶんげん is the 漢音 reading. Although kanji compounds (熟語) can in principle have both readings (in addition to any number of customary ones), it seems it is more common to have only one.

Comment: It seems my latest answers keep attracting a -1.

Comment: The -1 is probably from the same person that downvoted one of my answers today.

Comment: Lately anyone's answers attract a -1.