# What is the difference between 乗り場 and バス停?

Tags: word-choice

I've seen them both with the meaning of 'Bus Stop.' Could someone please explain how they're different?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Firstly, のりば is not limited to buses. It means essentially "getting on point". (Cf. タクシーのりば "taxi stand".) There's a word for "getting off point" as well: おりば (降り場).

バスのりば is used in larger terminals for indicating where the bus stops are. The individual platforms are sometimes numbered as 1番のりば, 2番のりば, etc., or 1番線, 2番線, etc.

A バス停 (short for バス停留所) is a "conventional" bus stop outside a terminal. I would think of it as a sign at the side of a road, where a bus stops. Usually, for most bus lines, the のりば and おりば are one and the same—some people get off the bus, others get on. Calling a バス停 a のりば (or おりば) would only really make sense to disambiguate のりば from おりば for a particular (group of) bus lines. For example, there may be a roadside bus stop outside a large bus/train terminal, which is the おりば for a bus line whose のりば is inside the terminal.

Comment: Why are both the above answers being voted down? Both seem to be from users who have taken the time to provide perfectly correct straight forward answers for a straight forward question. (Troll best ignored?)

Comment: @Tim [Lately anyone's answers attract a -1.](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/14125/1628)

Answer (score 9):

I'm not a native speaker of English. So my English sentense would have many wrong term...

"乗り場" is the word that means place to get on vehicles. "バス停" means a "bus stop". We use it for only the bus.